# Using Firefox's "awesome" bar to search strings with periods?

Tags: firefox, domain-name

I was a Google Chrome user for a while, and that browser was pretty smart about figuring out whether something is a domain name (e.g. *date.com*) or something I want to google for (e.g. *DateTime.Parse*).

Firefox, on the other hand, *always* tries to resolve strings that contain periods as domain names, even if it makes no sense (".parse" is not an allowed top-level domain at the moment).

Can I somehow configure it to be smarter about it?

Addendum: Yes, I know that Firefox has a dedicated search box for search queries; I just don't want to make that little bit of mental effort every time I need something online.

Comment: @DavidPostill This looks like a workaround, rather than a solution -- adding a character that makes the query an invalid URL. a) It means altering your query (the **%27** in the address string), and b) at this point you might as well type "?" instead, and use the browser's [search keywords](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html) functionality. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Mihai: Your question is a duplicate though. If you don't like the accepted answer to the previous question you can always add a bounty to it.